# List Available Wireless Networks from Command Line

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking

I'm currently trying to do some physical debugging with one of our devices.  It would be very useful to be able to use a command to output a list of available wireless networks to the command line or to a file (which I could then run a diff on later).  Is there a way to do this in Windows 7?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Try NetShell.

The command [`netsh wlan show networks`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755301#bkmk_wlanShowNetworks) should work for you.

You can save output to a text file by using redirection like so:

```
netsh wlan show networks > somefile.txt
```

Comment: if you add *mode=bssid* to the end, it shows what channel each network is using too.

Comment: Does not work for me on the Windows 10. I have more than twenty Wi-Fi networks, but it shows only **one** network.

Comment: **`netsh` garbles Unicode SSIDs.** For the two different SSIDs “``” (4 octets) and “`F09FA78A`” (8 octets), `netsh wlan show networks` shows `SSID 3 : F09FA78A … SSID 4 : F09FA78A`.